# JavaScript: Retry on source 404

Tags: javascript

I could use some valuable help so I can figure out how to detect and work with the following error in Javascript.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (File Not Found)

What I would like to do is to keep trying fetching the file while getting a 404 until it's found.

It's about an audio stream.

Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE**: My work so far

```
document.getElementById('audio').addEventListener("ended",function() {
        this.src = "someSource";
        this.play();
    });`
```

This code detects when my audio source is down and reloads it. What I would like to do is to keep reloading the source until the server is up again

Comment: Could you provide the relevant JS code you already have?

Comment: Also, a screenshot of the console might be helpful.

Comment: @sp00m thank you for answering. I updated my post.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about recursion on promises.

You could get something similar to that (without mocking) (by resolving or rejecting promises in the appropriate events fired by the audio element)

Basically you reinvoke your function on the fail callback

```js
// this function mocks an asynchronous call which fails 5 times before succeeding
var mockAsynchronousLoad = (function() {
  var counter = 0;
  return function(url) {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    setTimeout(function() {
      if (counter >= 5) {
        d.resolve("mymusic.mp3");
        counter = 0;
      } else {
        d.reject("404");
        counter++;
      }
    }, 200);
    return d.promise();
  }
}());


var repeatLoad = (function() {
  var failed = 0;

  return function(limit) {
    mockAsynchronousLoad()
      .done(function(a) {
        document.write("fetched: " + a + "<br>");
        failed = 0;
      }).fail(function(a) {
        document.write("failed with: " + a + "<br>");
        if (failed++ < limit) {
          document.write("retrying <br>");
          repeatLoad(limit);
        } else {
          document.write("too many failures<br>");
          failed = 0;
        }
      });
  };
}());

repeatLoad(10);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```